# Java built-in data structure for mapping adjacent rooms

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm looking for a Java built-in data structure that would be the best at handling adjacent rooms.
I have a grid/floor divided into randomly generated rooms like so:

```
 + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + +
 +                         +           +
 +                         +           +
 +                         +           +
 +                         +           +
 +                         +           +
 +                         +           +
 +                         +           +
 + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + +
 +         +         +                 +
 +         +         +                 +
 +         +         +                 +
 +         +         +                 +
 +         +         +                 +
 + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + +
 +         +             +             +
 +         +             +             +
 +         +             +             +
 +         +             +             +
 + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + + +
```

and i'm looking for a data structure in which it would be fastest/easiest to store this grid and map out what rooms neighbour what rooms.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

thanks

Comment: Are rooms guaranteed rectangular? Walls always aligned with x/y axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a graph to represent rooms as nodes and neighboring relationship as edges.

You can represent graphs in many different ways. In this case, since the relationship is sparse, it's better to use adjacency list instead of adjacency matrix.

In Java, the graph can be represented with `Map<Room,List<Room>>`. Basically, it is what it says: it's a map from a `Room` to a list of its neighboring `Room`s.

Alternatively, if you prefer to work with basic integers and arrays, you can use an adjacency matrix representation `boolean[][] adj`, where `adj[i][j] == true` if and only if room `i` and room `j` are neighbors.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to store:

1. the opposite corners of each room
2. the [adjacency graph/matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) of the graph formed by rooms as nodes and adjacency as the edge.